# upload autocomplete xml files to google search engine using c#

Tags: c#, php, google-search-api

I am using the google search engine.

I can add autocomplete terms and upload an xml file with the autocompletetion terms.

I am trying to auto upload this xml file by a console application or a php file.Is there a way that I can auto-upload this xml file using c# or php or any language?

this is an image for clarification

http://postimage.org/image/6kldz1vnb/

Comment: Auto-upload it to what location?

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently changed the layout and features under Custom Search. I have been trying to upload an auto complete file and seems like this feature is still not working correctly.

Also, you can only upload an xml file which will have a defined format explained in the Help section.

Comment: It has some limits in the autocomplete terms that's why it's not working correctly with you.
I know the format and how to upload but I am searching for an api that can help me develop an automated service that upload to google custom search engine by itself according to the most repeated search words that are being searched in my site.